# manipulate EXIF data on ios 7, armv7

Tags: ios, exif, armv7, armv6

I tried to use the [iphone-exif library](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/) but it seems that this wont work on armv7 only 6 or below. I am new to ios dev and am curious if there is another solution or a way to compile this for armv7?

I am in need of a way to both read and write the metadata for orientation issues and geolocation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got an answer as this was posted a while ago but here's my thoughts.

You can use CGImageDestinationSetProperties, since iOS4 to add metadata to set of images in a destination. It includes EXIF, IPTC and a *lot* of other information.

Check out the Image I/O Programming guide on Apple's dev site for more.The documentation references OS X mostly but it's all applicable to iOS.
Basically you're creating CGImageRefs from files or data, putting them somewhere then applying properties to them.